# download.file() produces "invalid" zip file on Windows but works fine on Mac

Tags: r, windows, macos, download, zip

The following line of R code (running in RStudio) downloads the zip file on my Mac (macOS Sierra) as well as my Windows machine (Windows 10).

```
download.file("https://sdi.noe.gv.at/OGD/at.gv.noe.geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=OGD:KAT_GEM_200&srsName=EPSG:31259&outputFormat=shape-zip", "KAT_GEM_200.zip")
```

However, the zip file downloaded by my Windows machine seems to be corrupted. I get an "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder ... is invalid." error message when I try to unzip it. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I need to be able to run the code on both computers.

## More information

The Windows machine can unzip the file downloaded on the Mac, and the Mac also gives an error message when I try to open the file downloaded by the Windows machine.

The zip folder does not get corrupted on the Windows machine, when I just put https://sdi.noe.gv.at/OGD/at.gv.noe.geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=OGD:KAT_GEM_200&srsName=EPSG:31259&outputFormat=shape-zip into my internet browser and download it like that.

The zip file downloaded by the Windows machine has 4182KB, the one downloaded my the Mac (or through the browser on Windows) only 4172KB.

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out. I had to set `mode = "wb"`.

```
download.file("https://sdi.noe.gv.at/OGD/at.gv.noe.geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=OGD:KAT_GEM_200&srsName=EPSG:31259&outputFormat=shape-zip", "KAT_GEM_200.zip", mode = "wb")
```

Comment: Oddly, the help file says "On Windows, if mode is not supplied (missing()) and url ends in one of .gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz, .zip, .jar, .rda, .rds or .RData, mode = "wb" is set so that a binary transfer is done to help unwary users." This apparently has no effect, since there is a default mode of "w", and this automatic setting to "wb" doesn't get reached.